# How to put an input check for a calculator in python?

Tags: python, input, while-loop, calculator

```
print("Welcome to the Kinetic Energy and Gravitational Potential Energy Calculator")
print("Which Calculator would you like to access?")

Choice = str(input("Type in KE for Kinetic Energy and GPE for Gravitational Potential Energy:"))

while Choice != "KE" or "GPE":
    print("Error. You have not entered a valid choice. Please type KE or GPE.")
    Choice = str(input("Type in KE for Kinetic Energy and GPE for Gravitational Potential Energy:"))


while Choice == "KE":
    print("You have chosen the Kinetic Energy Calculator.")
    mass = float(input("Type in the mass of the object in kilograms (kg):"))
    velocity = float(input("Type in the velocity of the object in metres per second (m/s):"))
    result = 0.5*mass*(velocity**2)
    print("The KE is:", result, "J(Joules)")
    Choice = str(input("Type in KE for Kinetic Energy and GPE for Gravitational Potential Energy:"))

while Choice == "GPE":
    print("You have chosen the Gravitational Potential Energy Calculator.")
    mass = float(input("Type in the mass of the object in kilograms (kg):"))
    height = float(input("Type in the height at which the object is in metres (m):"))
    result = 9.81*mass*height
    print("The GPE is:", result, "J(Joules)")
    Choice = str(input("Type in KE for Kinetic Energy and GPE for Gravitational Potential Energy:"))
```

I have tried using "or" so the check can include both 'KE' and 'GPE', but when you run the program, even if I input KE or GPE, the first while loop keeps going! How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your condition. Since `"GPE"` is logically `True` (Non empty string is logically `True`), the while loop condition is always `True`, No matter what the choice is.

Change:

```
Choice != "KE" or "GPE"
```

to:

```
Choice != "KE" and Choice != "GPE"
```

or:

```
Choice not in ["KE","GPE"]
```